# Why are there different versions of this character?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In *The Flash* Season 2 Episode 18 we found out that

> Jay is Zoom and that his real name is Hunter Zolomon

we also know about his past

> on my Earth, Hunter Zolomon was a convicted serial killer.
> That's Jay? No, that is Hunter.
> Last public photo of Hunter Zolomon.
> Instantly recognizable.
> When Hunter was 11, his father killed his mother right in front of him.
> Father sent to prison, Hunter grew up in the foster care system.
> Years later he was convicted on 23 counts of murder.
> After the trial, Hunter was sent to the Saint Perez Mental Asylum for the Criminally Insane given daily electroshock therapy. Cure him of his urges and then faded from view. Until the night your particle accelerator exploded.
> That's right.
> The dark matter crept into the mental asylum.
> I had thought piping the explosion underground would limit exposure.
> I was wrong.
> All it did was create an unstoppable monster.

Then we find out that

> the Jay that's been helping Barry and team Flash and dies, was a time remnant of Zoom's past self and was never real
> How are you still alive? We saw you die.
> You did.
> So what was that? A speed mirage? [chuckles] Speed mirage? Uh, no.
> Even I'm not that fast.
> I knew that I couldn't be on two Earths at the same time, so I went back in time and, uh, met another version of myself.
> Your time remnant.
> Like the Reverse-Flash.
> I also knew that the only way to make Barry become faster was if you all witnessed your old pal Jay die.
> When did you decide to do that? Oh, once you closed all the breaches, went to Earth-2.
> Believe me, getting my time remnant to agree to me murdering him took a bit of convincing.
> But once he saw the well, the genius in my plan, he was all for it.

So why are there multiple versions of

> Jay Garrick and why did the past self of  hunter agree with zoom to murder him in front of Barry and the team and why was his past self a time remnant last why would zoom go back in time and ask his past self to be the Flash and fight him and to go to earth 1 and help Barry and the team to train for Barry's battle with Zoom.

Comment: im asking why are there multiple jay garicks

Comment: Spoilers corrected. It still has grammatical and formatting issues which you might want to concentrate on. Also, try not to have too much spoiler content since it makes the question almost unreadable.

Comment: thats why i was putting spoliert tags so pepole whos not seen it cant be spoiled

Comment: You don't necessarily need the amount of transcript you've entered. Since it's in a spoiler block, those who haven't seen the episode won't look, and those who have will know what you're talking about anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see three <strike>Jay Garricks</strike> Hunter Zolomons:

- Earth-1 Hunter - in the park. This is the one that "Jay" and Caitlin watch. He has no active involvement in the plot. Much like [communism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7e16yDFjdc), he's just a red herring.
- Earth-2 Zoom/Hunter-Prime (surviving). This is the one still currently alive, who just acquired more of the Speed force.
- Earth-2 Zoom/Hunter-Remnant (dead). This is the one that Zoom killed in front of everyone.

Like the Reverse-Flash, Zoom needed Barry to run faster, for the intended goal of stealing his improved abilities. For Thawne, it was to go to back to the future; for Zolomon, it appears to be able to cure whatever sickness is killing him.

Zoom-Prime was able to convince Zoom-Remnant to die so that Zoom, as an entity may live. Why would Zoom-Remnant agree to this? He's not exactly sane. He's spent some undetermined time going through daily shock therapy, and has become detached from feeling any remorse or guilt.

> Barry: And you just don't care how many lives you destroy trying to get it? How many people you kill?
>
> Zoom-Prime: No, I don't! That feeling was taken from me a long time ago.

Like the Reverse-Flash, both Earth-2 Zooms understood that the key to their survival was the long game. Zoom-Prime explains to Team-Flash that he needed to be in two places at the same time to be able to convince everyone that he was on their side. It's a brutal plan, for sure, but one that a murderous dying psychopath is willing to agree to.

Similar discussion about *The Prestige* (spoiler warning): [Why would Robert Angier use the machine every time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100183/5184)

Comment: Ok but this doesn't make sense. If he went back in time and looked for another version of himself, who later died... shouldn't he instantly disappear ? Like when reverse flash disappeared when Eddie killed himelf at the end of season 1 ? Is this worthy of another question ?

Comment: so there was never a jay garrick

Comment: jay garrick was a false persona zolomon created to be the flash on earth-2.

Comment: Was the flash Jay and hunter zoom the same person

Comment: On Earth-2, Hunter Zolomon is Zoom and The Flash/"Jay Garrick". The "Jay Garrick" who came to Earth-1 was the Time-Remnant, while the Prime version remained back on Earth-2.

Comment: So they switched places during  the season

Comment: The hunter that showed catilin his doplaganger was zoom

Comment: Right now, it's unclear if they ever swapped places, or if Hunter-Prime and Hunter-Remnant were in communication somehow.

Comment: Why would zoom go back in time and tell his past self to be the flash and fight him and go to earth 1 and train Barry and be freida for his fight with zoom

Comment: DIdn't I already answer this on your other question? Zoom wants Barry being faster because it means more power to suck out of him.

Comment: If he killed his Past  self at the breach wouldn't that mean zoom wouldn't exist

Comment: See [this question and answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125855/5184)

Comment: If there are 2 hunters who's the man in the iron mask

Comment: I was _so_ hoping (and indeed was fairly sure) that Jay Garrick was indeed a nice guy Flash from Earth-2, and that Zoom would turn out to be some Jay Garrick from Earth-n. Sadly not. Blah. As far as I'm concerned they've made a bit of a mess instead :(

Comment: What kind of mess