# Shouldn't this character have disappeared?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the episode *Versus Zoom*, we learn that

> Zoom went back in time to get another version of himself to pretend to be Jay, and to let Zoom kill him.

Now, going on the previous episodes, such as

> when Eddie died and Eobard disappeared, shouldn't Zoom have disappeared if his past self had died?

Comment: I think you should wait until the end of the season to have a good answer.

Comment: For all we know,Zoom might be lying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that the Speed Force actually allows travel through time in *either* direction.

This video explains Time Remnants pretty well, but it's actually more likely that the time remnant he used as "Jay" was from the *future*, not the past. By killing a Time Remnant from the future, Zoom remains in existence.